# Почему в python не допускается смешивание языков?

Tags: python

Глупый вопрос, как всегда откуда не думал. Решил назвать переменную на двух языках английский и русский,  #циfра=1# , допустим, но выдалась ошибка, сразу задался вопросом, почему в python и в Pycharm в частности нельзя смешивать языки?
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: у меня все работает

Comment: Тоже проверил в Google Colab - работает без проблем. А Python какой версии у автора вопроса?

Comment: Python 3.9 (32-bit)

Comment: Можно, потому что и русский алфавит и английский — это символы Unicode. Пожалуйста, приведите ошибку, которая у Вас возникает в вопрос. Возможно, что проблема в другом.

Comment: Symbols from different languages found: [LATIN, CYRILLIC]

Comment: и Non-ASCII characters in an identifier

Comment: Проверил, работает. Возможно, вы сохраняете свой файл не в кодировке utf-8

Comment: File | Settings | Editor | File Encodings ,уже был установлен utf-8

Comment: Это ругается IDE, поскольку в большинстве случаев это ошибка из-за невнимательности и человеку сложно различить `e` и русскую `е`, `c` и русскую `c` и т.д. К тому же смешивание считается плохой практикой.